# Unable to get user hometown and location from Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get user `hometown` and `location` using Facebook graph API for the logged-in user

Public permissions to fetch location and hometown is granted by the user.

Graph API version **v2.8**

```
/me?fields=name,picture,location,hometown
```

Comment: _“Public permissions to fetch location and hometown is granted by the user”_ - did you _verify_ that, or do you just _assume_ that, because you put the permissions into the login button scope?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask for permissions: `user_hometown` and `user_location`. The hometown/location is not included in the public permissions.

You can also check the scope of your access token [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/)

Comment: <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,user_hometown,user_location,email,name" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

Comment: Code for login button

Comment: I have added user_hometown,user_location in scope but still getting this response

Comment: Object {status: "connected", authResponse: Object}
authResponse
:
Object
status
:
"connected"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Did you checked the access token debugger? (link i mentioned in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the complete user profile using FB token:

I am assuming you have given permission before getting token from graph api explore which is:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

```js
public Profile GetProfile(string facebookID)
        {
            var url = "?fields=first_name,last_name,name,age_range,birthday, education, gender, hometown, locale, location, third_party_id, timezone, email";

            dynamic result = _facebookClient.Get(facebookID + url);

            var profile = new Profile();

            if (result != null)
            {
                string resultStringify = result.ToString();
                var resultBlock = JObject.Parse(resultStringify);
             
                //if (result.ToString().Contains("first_name")) {
                //    profile.First_Name = resultBlock["first_name"].ToString();
                //}
                profile.First_Name = resultStringify.ExtractIfValueIsAvailable("first_name", resultBlock);
                //if (result.ToString().Contains("last_name")) {
                //    profile.Last_Name = resultBlock["last_name"].ToString();
                //}
                profile.Last_Name = resultStringify.ExtractIfValueIsAvailable("last_name", resultBlock);
                //if (result.ToString().Contains("name")) {
                //    profile.Name = resultBlock["name"].ToString();
                //}
                profile.Name = resultStringify.ExtractIfValueIsAvailable("name", resultBlock);

                if (result.ToString().Contains("age_range"))
                {
                    if (result.age_range.min != null) profile.Age_Range_Min = result.age_range.min;
                    if (result.age_range.max != null) profile.Age_Range_Max = result.age_range.max;
                }

                //if (result.ToString().Contains("birthday")) {
                //    profile.Birthday = DateTime.ParseExact(result.birthday, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                //}
                profile.Birthday = resultStringify.ExtractIfDateTime("birthday", resultBlock);
                //if (result.ToString().Contains("gender")) {
                //    profile.Gender = resultBlock["gender"].ToString();
                //}
                profile.Gender = resultStringify.ExtractIfValueIsAvailable("gender", resultBlock);
                //if (result.ToString().Contains("hometown")) {
                //    profile.Hometown = resultBlock["hometown"]["name"].ToString();
                //}
                profile.Hometown = resultStringify.ExtractIfNameValueIsAvailable("hometown", resultBlock);
                //if (result.ToString().Contains("locale")) {
                //    profile.Locale = resultBlock["locale"].ToString();
                //}
                profile.Locale = resultStringify.ExtractIfValueIsAvailable("locale", resultBlock);
                //if (result.ToString().Contains("location")) {
                //    profile.Location = resultBlock["location"]["name"].ToString();
                //}
                profile.Location = resultStringify.ExtractIfNameValueIsAvailable("location", resultBlock);
                //if (result.ToString().Contains("third_party_id")) {
                //    profile.Third_Party_ID = resultBlock["third_party_id"].ToString();
                //}

                profile.Third_Party_ID = resultStringify.ExtractIfValueIsAvailable("third_party_id", resultBlock);

                profile.Timezone = resultStringify.ExtractIfValueIsAvailable("timezone", resultBlock);

                profile.EMail = resultStringify.ExtractIfValueIsAvailable("email", resultBlock);

            }

           
            return profile;
        }

public static string ExtractIfValueIsAvailable(this string result, string fieldName, dynamic resultBlock) => result.Contains(fieldName) ? resultBlock[fieldName].ToString() : string.Empty;
```

Hope it helps.